# org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser$ParseException: At line 1, column 0: syntax error

Tags: android, xml, parsing

I am attempting to run my app with Apache server, yet the error below appears upon attempting to login:

```
06-22 20:41:40.646  23626-23626/com.example.feastapp W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
06-22 20:41:40.646  23626-23626/com.example.feastapp W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
06-22 20:41:42.711  23626-24033/com.example.feastapp W/System.err﹕ org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser$ParseException: At line 1, column 0: syntax error
06-22 20:41:42.711  23626-24033/com.example.feastapp W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.finish(ExpatParser.java:545)
06-22 20:41:42.711  23626-24033/com.example.feastapp W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.parseDocument(ExpatParser.java:475)
06-22 20:41:42.711  23626-24033/com.example.feastapp W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatReader.parse(ExpatReader.java:316)
06-22 20:41:42.716  23626-24033/com.example.feastapp W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatReader.parse(ExpatReader.java:279)
06-22 20:41:42.716  23626-24033/com.example.feastapp W/System.err﹕ at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:390)
06-22 20:41:42.716  23626-24033/com.example.feastapp W/System.err﹕ at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:187)
06-22 20:41:42.716  23626-24033/com.example.feastapp W/System.err﹕ at com.example.infrastructure.serve.MessagingService.parseFriendInfo(MessagingService.java:592)
06-22 20:41:42.716  23626-24033/com.example.feastapp W/System.err﹕ at com.example.infrastructure.serve.MessagingService.getFriendList(MessagingService.java:309)
06-22 20:41:42.716  23626-24033/com.example.feastapp W/System.err﹕ at com.example.infrastructure.serve.MessagingService.authenticateUser(MessagingService.java:368)
06-22 20:41:42.716  23626-24033/com.example.feastapp W/System.err﹕ at com.example.feastapp.UserSessionManage.LoggingIn$2$1.run(LoggingIn.java:232)
```

Here is the MessagningService.java first error location:

```
private void parseFriendInfo(String xml) {
        try {
            SAXParser sp = SAXParserFactory.newInstance().newSAXParser();
            sp.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes()), new HandlerXML(
                    MessagingService.this));
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

This error does not occur when running on Android 5.0 however...

How can I make this work?

Comment: A first step would be to post the contents of MessagingService.java

Comment: The problem was not in the code, but the user input....nuff said